# Proper way to access a variable within a module while in parent module

Tags: ruby, module

Let's say for instance I have the following case:

```
module A
  module B

    def self.make
      @correlation_id ||= SecureRandom.uuid
    end

  end
end
```

Now, for the outside world, I only want them to be able to access correlation_id through module A:

`A.correlation_id`. How would I access `@correlation_id` from module A?

I did the following, and it worked, but had a side-effect I didn't want.

```
module A
  module B

    def self.make
      @correlation_id ||= SecureRandom.uuid
    end

    private

    def self.correlation_id
      @correlation_id
    end
  end

  def self.correlation_id
    A::B.correlation_id
  end
end
```

With that in place, after I do `A::B.make`, I could do `A.correlation_id`, but sadly I am also able to do `A::B.correlation_id`. How would I alleviate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
module A
  module B
    def self.make
      @correlation_id ||= SecureRandom.uuid
    end
  end
  def self.correlation_id
    B.instance_variable_get("@correlation_id")
  end
end
```

For efficiency, put `.freeze` after `"@correlation_id"`.

Comment: This seems a bit meta. I'll definitely do this, but is there a more standard way? Just curious :)

Comment: What you are attempting is not standard in the first place (Allowing `A` to access `A::B`'s class instance variable without allowing `A::B` to do so is against OOP), so there is no standard way.

Comment: Why would `.freeze` make this more efficient?

Comment: Because the string will then be only created at parse time and reused. It is a feature introduced recently.